# Wordpress post thumb disappears after sharing on Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I share a articles from this blog on my FB page: http://what-is-your-story.co.za/blog/ - when it contains an image, it shows the image in the preview mode on facebook, but after I post the link, the image disappears. It just shows a white block where the image should be.
When I share an article from the same blog with no image, it still shows a blank thumbnail block where an image would've been (although there is none).

I've tested it with the Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger, and the link looks fine with the image showing up if the article has one and no image/thumb area when there isn't one. But still if I share the articles on Facebook, it shows a blank thumbnail area for all these articles.

The same happens when someone else shares these posts as well.

Some screenshots of what I see in FB Debugger and what is actually posted: [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTxX8.png)

Website / blog built on: Wordpress V4.4.2 | Gantry 5 framework V5.2.10 with Hydrogen theme

Any ideas on what causes this and how I can fix this?

PS: Sharing to Google+ shows the images just fine. No problem there. It seems to just be Facebook.

Comment: Facebook relies on something called Open Graph (OG) tags. You need to place them the `<head>` of your page's html code. Since you're on  Wordpress you might need to **[try a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wonderm00ns-simple-facebook-open-graph-tags/)**. Also Facebook will sometimes scan a shared page for pictures coming from that same domain. Basically upload a picture to the post if you want to see that picture when sharing in FB.